# Can anyone help identify this old terminal and printer found in an abandoned nuclear power plant?

Tags: terminal, identify-this-computer, identify-this-peripheral

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/ONEm1ph3MP4?t=2244) on Youtube of some guys exploring an abandoned nuclear power plant(I believe to be in the US or Canada) that was decommissioned around 1991, and noticed this equipment at one point.  Google image search doesn't seem to find anything, although I'm sure one of you guys will recognize at least one of the pieces of equipment on sight...

[image: Workstation]

I'm surprised by the large size of the CRT for the time.  Seems obvious it would be monochrome and not color, because a color data CRT that size would have been rare at the time. Here is a photo of the same keyboard from a different workstation closer up:

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: To start with, it might be quite helpful if you'd add at least what country that is supposed to be, not to mention items like former operator, etc.

Comment: Details on the location of the plant, and the approximate time the plant was constructed and last operated, would be helpful.  Computer manufacturers restricted to a single national market were common well into the 1990s.

Comment: @Raffzahn - These  guys that "explore" these abandoned places always try to conceal, to some degree, the actual location of the property they are exploring.  They do, however, usually leave enough clues in their videos that the location could be revealed with enough research.  I just wanted to see if anyone recognized them visually, without a lot of research.  BTW, there is some mainframe stuff toward the end of the video...

Comment: I feel like the first word in the label on the printer is "GENERAL" but I can't make out the second word. General Electric? General Atomics? Below, it looks like the profile of an old airplane like a DC-1/C-47.

Comment: @snips-n-snails - Actually, someone in the Youtube comments said they recognized the plant after watching the video.  They said it was a "General Electric BWR" type nuclear reactor and, in fact, throughout the video, most of the junction box and panel labels all said "General Electric", so that makes sense.  I have just never heard of GE making a printer.  Guess I should google that..

Comment: GE did make printers - I worked at a small company that was a VAR (value added reseller) - common back in the day, mid 80’s - and we were a dealer for GENICOM printers, which was an offshoot of GE. Cool bat phone on top.... hope that never had to be used!

Comment: Could ti have been a custom keyboard?

Comment: @Hitek THe question wasn't the exact place, but the COUNTRY. where on this planet, as there are in fact multiple states in existence.

Comment: @Raffzahn - They never stated the country, either, and I can't just go by the nationality of the explorers, as they are from the US but explore everywhere in the world.  Based on the video, I would have to assume it could be any location with English as its primary language...

Comment: The video at timestamp 46m27s shows a building that matches the Shoreham, NY Nuclear Power Station, decommissioned by 1994. https://www.roadsideamerica.com/tip/43645

Comment: was the red telephone meant to call the President just in case something went wrong ?

Comment: The keyboard has the dollar sign and not pound sign. On white there is extra parenthesis (but not accented characters), OTOH maybe there is some deadkey, so I'm more about to exclude Canada.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi When I was growing up in an anglophone part of Ontario in the 90s, everyone I knew was using keyboards marked only for the US 101 and later US 104 layouts, so you can't really make any judgments about Canada based purely on keyboard layout.

Comment: The only thing I could add is that it is not a US keyboard - that's an old style UK keyboard layout. The obvious giveaways are the " above the 2, and the () brackets above 8 and 9, not 9 and 0. That layout is still used in standard Japanese keyboards today. Just based on that, I suspect the location is not in the US. At any rate, the equipment looks like UK gear, if I had to make a guess.

Comment: The answer to this question was posted 3 years ago in the video comments by Paul Crissman.

Comment: @JdeBP And that answer is? Google's not sorting Paul Crissman's comment anywhere near the top of the list when I visit the video.

Comment: @JdeBP - Yea, that was nice of the guy to go through over 8000 comments to find the answer, and then not share it with us.  I, too, tried to find the comment he referenced, but could not, despite me having gone through almost half of them all.  I did see mentions of CDC 6000 series mainframes and CDC 877 data packs, though...

Comment: Regarding the monitors, I worked in a utility control center in 1991, and it was full of CRTs around that size. (19in, 1280x1024, 16 color). Dispatchers would get a a console with four and there were also 2 and 3 CRT consoles for dev and others. Each console had a custom keyboard with ~300 keys for quick jumping around various UI pages. Back end was two redundant computer rooms, each with a pair of CDC Cyber 180's (related to the 6600) and around 30-40GB disk storage. Heady stuff, but it kept fuel costs down and the lights lit, so there was money/reason to pay for it.

Comment: @mschaef - WOW! Would love to see a write up on this!

Comment: The keyboard layout may not be indicative of country: it appears to be a [bit-paired keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-paired_keyboard) where the layout is designed for ease of decoding shifted keys rather than following existing typewriter/computer standards. Odd that one would still be rattling around in 1991 though…

Comment: @CalebFuller that arrangement of punctuation above the numbers actually predates the PC.  It's based on the bit codes for ASCII.  You can see an example in the [Teletype ASR 33 keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33#/media/File:Mappa_Teletype_ASR-33.jpg).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would have written just a comment but did not have enough rep to do so. @JdeBP had basically found the answer so all I had to google was "Youtube comment finder" :).

The video also posts a linked reddit discussion which clears up the first question everyone asked:
The plant is [Shoreham Nuclear Power Plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoreham_Nuclear_Power_Plant), decommissioned in 1994 and completed by General Electric in the mid 80s.

As the @JdeBP has pointed out there is a [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONEm1ph3MP4&lc=Ugy31S6A9L2wEl8u3dV4AaABAg) by Paul Crissman, which I'll quote in case the link goes down: "The **GE MAC7000** line was bought out by Bailey controls Co. I worked there 1975-1995. The Keyboard was an **Intecolor** which was a data terminal that connected to more modern digital controllers in the **Network 90 system**".

So, first off, the entire plant ran a [distributed control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_control_system) meaning what we're seeing as a keyboard under a huge CRT is indeed, as Hitek has tagged it, a terminal for the General Electric turned Bailey control system.

The fun part, now knowing what it is, is googling [Intecolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compucolor) and learning in a small Wikipedia snippet that the Intercolor 8001 was a kit-based terminal based on the Intel 8080 and the CRT produced what is described as bright and colorful pictures.

And since these control systems have become increasingly expensive to maintain there is actually an [emulator](https://www.pc8800.com/pc8800.html) provided for sale by a company whose website not only shows the aforementioned graphics(emulated) but also a picture of such a terminal with the Intercolor keyboard layout as seen in the Youtube video.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is Shoreham in the USA, not Shoreham in England.